# Cannot upgrade applications on a used mac mini.  "iPhoto is registered to different user"?

Tags: mac-mini, iphoto

My computer was bought from best buy they say they wiped it clean it was a return from less than 10 days.  When I put in my details on the mac everything went fine.  There is an update for iPhoto and when I try to update it tells me that I need to sign in with a different account I do not have those details?

How can I remove any artifact of the previous user?